# MapStruct not working in service class while running Test cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, mapstruct

I am creating test cases, in one of my service class method I am using `mapStruct` to map entity into dto class.

This is my mapper class

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
    
    List<UserDto> toUserDto(List<UserEntity> users);
    }
```

below is how I am injecting in my service class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    private final UserMapper userMapper;
```

This is how I am using it

```
List<UserDto> userDto = userMapper.toUserDto(lst);
```

this is how I am doing it in my Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)

public class ApplicationTest {
    
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    
    @Mock
    private UserMapper userMapper;
    
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        then(controller).isNotNull();
        then(userServiceImpl).isNotNull();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void getAllUser() {
        List<UserEntity> lst = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();
        UserEntity userOne = new UserEntity();
        userOne.setEmpFullname("Test Test1");
        userOne.setUserId("marina");
        userOne.setFlag("Y");
        UserEntity usertwo = new UserEntity();
        usertwo.setEmpFullname("Test Test2");
        usertwo.setUserId("test");
        usertwo.setFlag("Y");
        lst.add(userOne);
        lst.add(usertwo);
        
        when(userRepo.findByStatus("W")).thenReturn(lst);
        try {
            List<UserDto> pendingUsersList = userServiceImpl.getPendingUser();
            assertEquals(2, pendingUsersList.size());
            
        } catch (GeneralException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

when I am running my test cases I am able to see these 2 records in entity class but when this line executes

`List<UserDto> userDto = userMapper.toUserDto(lst);` it gives me blank array.

Note - In my entity Class I have many fields but from test class I am passing only 3 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have annotated your UserMapper with a @Mock annotation, without writing the mockito configuration for this mock. Then the blank array is expected.
Remove the @Mock annotation, or specify what should be returned by the mock. 
For example :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)

public class ApplicationTest {
    
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    
    @Spy
    private UserMapper userMapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
    
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
```

Comment: if I remove @Mock, the I get error at this line
`List<UserDto> userDto = userMapper.toUserDto(lst);`
what configuration I need to do, can you please guide

Comment: try to replace the `@Mock` with `@Spy` on your userMapper and provide the instance, It should use the real object. If it doesn't work, please share the error.

Comment: it given me the same blank array if I replace `@Mock` with `@Spy`

Comment: I added an example in the response